# Calculating the limit of fractions for uniform convergence

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, fractions

I'm trying to calculate the limit sup of a term and see if it equals zero in order to prove uniform convergence. I arrive at this:
$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f_{n}-f(x)| = $
$\lim_{n\to \infty}(1-\frac{n}{n+2})(\frac{n}{n+2})^\frac{n}{2}$
now how I solved the limit is such:

$\lim_{n\to \infty}(1-\frac{n}{n+2})(\frac{n}{n+2})^\frac{n}{2} $

$=\lim_{n\to \infty}(1-\frac{n}{n(1+2/n)})(\frac{n}{n(1+2/n)})^\frac{n}{2}$

the first term equals 1-1 since 2/n converges zero. hence the limit is qual zero, which is also what is said in the solution. However they calculated the limit in a completely other way, one where you get terms such as e^-1, but the limit still equals zero. My qustion is: is my method correct?

here how it's solved in the textbook:

$\lim_{n\to \infty}(1-\frac{n}{n+2})(\frac{n}{n+2})^\frac{n}{2} $
$=\lim_{n\to \infty}(1-\frac{n}{n+2})(1-\frac{2}{n+2})^\frac{n}{2} $
$=\lim_{n\to \infty}(1-\frac{n}{n+2})\frac{1}{e} = 0 $

I do not understand the last line of this solution at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your help

Comment: It should be `\infty` for $\infty$, not $infinity$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** We have $(1 + \frac{x}{n})^n \rightarrow \exp(x)$